# Assignment of long string is working in one oracle scehma where as it is not working in another for same DB version

Tags: oracle, plsql, clob

Oracle DB version is 11gR2

Code is as below:
    Select Extractvalue(p_Xml                                  ,'/FCUBS_REQ_ENV/FCUBS_BODY/FLD/FN[@TYPE="' || l_Temp_Str || '"][position()=last()]')
                Into   l_Temp_Str
                From   Dual;
l_Temp_Str IS CLOB type;

p_Ts_Clob_Tag_Values := p_Ts_Clob_Tag_Values ||Dbms_Xmldom.Getnodevalue(l_Child_Node) || '>';

`p_Ts_Clob_Tag_Values`  is out variable in that function where above code is wrirren.

Schema A and B,everything is same.Both the schema was made in sync one day before.

Schema A,while assigning in the SQL query in above code does not show any problem.

Schema B,while assigning above code does thorws error.i.e. PLSQL buffer character string too small.

Why is it so!!

Please help.

Comment: Try `to_clob(your_entire_expression)`

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: @Tejash That is not working..The server in which schema B is installed is not physical server.DB is installed on virtual server.Is there any parameter setting for memory usage related to CLOB or BLOB?